# Converting a string from a txt file to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have uploaded a txt file into python that I am going to attempt to sort. Although, when I upload it, it becomes a string in python and I would like to instead use an array. I have attempted to use np.array, as well as attempting to open it with pandas and create it from there. I am relatively new to python so Im sure its pretty simple, but I would appreciate any help. Here's what I've attempted:

```
    stroke = open('2018cut.txt', 'r')
    stroke = stroke.read()
    print(stroke)
    type(stroke)
```

- 2018-07-07 00:00:57.849  40.3512 -103.8954    +3.6  C
- 2018-07-07 00:00:58.152  40.7638 -102.6134    +4.4  C
- 2018-07-07 00:00:58.862  40.5501 -104.1176   +10.8  C
- class 'str'

This is my output. I would like to create an array like this, rather than it being a string. So I tried:

```
    strokes=np.array([stroke])
```

After this, I end up getting np.array as my output for type(strokes), but it puts it all in a 1x0 array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to read the entire file into a single list, where each element of the list is a line from the file, then use `.readlines()` instead of `.read()`.

However, if your file is large, then you may not want to load it all into memory at once.  You can process a file one line at a time like this:

```
stroke = open('2018cut.txt', 'r')
for line in stroke:
    # do stuff with line
```